# New to c++, need tips for OOP

Tags: c++

I just want to say that this is my first time trying to learn a programming language so excuse my indifference. I am trying to get used to object oriented programming. The problem is I can't figure out how to get what the user inputted without storing it in a public variable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Aclass{
public:
    void setx(int a){
        x = a;
    }
    void sety(int b){
        y = b;
    }
    void setsum(int c){
        c = sum;
    }
    int getx(){
        return x;
    }
    int gety(){
        return y;
    }
    int getsum(){
        return sum;
    }

private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int sum;
    int diff;
    int mult;
    int div;
};

int main()
{
    string NB;
    cout << "What you like to do ?(Sum, Difference, Multiplication or Division)\n";
    cin >> NB;

    if(NB == "Sum") {
        Aclass Ab;
        cout << "Enter Your First Number\n";
        Ab.setx(cin >> a);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: First tip: don't write classes that just hold data and have a getter and a setter for each data member. There is no point in doing that.

Comment: `AB.setx(cin >> a)` compiles?

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't think that's true. But this is kind of off-topic here, so we probably shouldn't discuss that in this comment-section.

Comment: @TheMotivation It is true, and OP is asking for tips for OOP programming. It is a good tip.

Comment: Another OOP tip (avoiding setters): read in the parameters to local variables and pass them to the constructor (`Aclass(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}`).

Comment: @juanchopanza: it's a reasonable tip, but a tip without some explanation or links isn't a great idea as the OP has no way to judge its worth, and on SO you have to expect a mix of quality of advice.  Not the end of the world if it's easy to google, but sometimes it can be difficult for them to know what to look for.

Comment: You also shouldn't store the result (unless there is good reason) but let the class calculate as needed (`int getSum() { return x + y; }`)

Comment: @user3824549 You should point out explicitly that there is a compilation error, and at which line. A quote from an error message might be good. That would make your question more understandable and easy to answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone as I said I am very new to c++ (started watching youtube tutorials two days ago). I was doing fine until he started with this OOP which kinda got me confused. To Adriano Ab.setx(cin >> a) is a mistake, I probably shouldn't have written it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the user input in a variable, then pass it to `Ab.setx` to store the variable in the object, i.e.

```
int main() {
    // Declare your variables
    Aclass Ab;
    string choice;
    int x, y;

    // Get user choice
    cout << "What you like to do? (Sum, Diff, Mul or Div)" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    // Get user inputs
    if (choice == "Sum") {
        cout << "Enter your first number" << endl;
        cin >> x;           // Get the user input from 'cin' and store it in 'a'
        cout << "Enter your second number" << endl;
        cin >> y;

        // Pass x, y to the Ab object and store them there
        Ab.setx(x);
        Ab.sety(y);

        cout << "The final sum is: " << Ab.getsum() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: the above code requires an implement of `getsum` as follows:

```
class Aclass{
// ...
public:
    int getsum(){
        return (this->x + this->y);
    }
// ...
```

Comment: +1 for pointing in the right direction (although `Ab.set...` and a final `cout << "The sum is " << Ab.getsum() << '\n';` *inside* the `if` block would be even nicer).

Comment: I was going to add the 'final sum' line, but then I realised OP hasn't implemented addition in his `getsum` method. I've edited my post with your changes anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I am going to continue coding my calculator hopefully no more problems show up.